# Create vectors within lappy (or loop)

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to loop a function over a vector of characters. The function will create a vector or a list, and the name of each vector (list) will be taken from the vector of characters. For example.

```
# The data would look like:
fist second third
1    2     3
1    NA    3
1    2     3
1    2     NA
NA   2     3

# I want to create three lists/vectors such as

first <- c("1.pdf", "1.pdf", "1.pdf", "1.pdf")
second <- c("2.pdf", "2.pdf", "2.pdf", "2.pdf")
third <- c("3.pdf", "3.pdf", "3.pdf", "3.pdf")

# where, first, second, third, now are the names of the vectors. I tried the following way. 

vector_names <- c("first", "second", "third")

cleanNA <- function(x){
  x <- as.character(as.data.frame(t(data[paste0(x)])))
  x <- na.omit(x) # remove all NA observations.
  x <- paste0(x, ".pdf")
  return(x)
}
# I can do this by a vector length 1. 

name <- c("first")
assign(name, namef)
namef <- createlists(name)

# But once I do an lapply, it won't create the three vectors as I wanted. The lapply does run and returns what I want, but not create the three vectors. 

lapply(vector_names, cleanNA)
```

I've been searching for this type of questions many times and feel R doesn't really provide a good way to generate a new vector within a loop. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've added an example, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version :

```
cleanNA <- function(data, x){
   x <- data[[x]]
   x <- na.omit(x) 
   x <- paste0(x, ".pdf")
   return(x)
   #Or a one-liner
   #paste0(na.omit(data[[x]]), '.pdf')
}

list_vec <- lapply(vector_names, cleanNA, data = data)
list_vec

#[[1]]
#[1] "1.pdf" "1.pdf" "1.pdf" "1.pdf"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2.pdf" "2.pdf" "2.pdf" "2.pdf"

#[[3]]
#[1] "3.pdf" "3.pdf" "3.pdf" "3.pdf"
```

It is better to keep data in a list so that it is easier to manage and avoids creating lot of objects in global environment. However, if you want them as separate vectors you can use `list2env` :

```
list_vec <- setNames(list_vec, vector_names)
list2env(list_vec, .GlobalEnv)
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(first = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), second = c(2L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L), third = c(3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this works for this example thank you. What if, there are 2 NAs in column 2 and 3 NAs in column 3, that is, the data frame won't be balanced after removing NAs? This is actually my situation but I didn't make the example clear. That was why I wanted to create separate vectors.

Comment: This will still work since `lapply` is returning a list and a list can have elements with different lengths.

Comment: Thank you!!!! setNames works now!! I tried to put setnames within the loop but didn't work, and didn't know about list2env. This solves my problem!! (without that list_vec, it won't change the dataframe)> But thank you anyway!! I should have asked instead of wasting 3 hours on this!